# What does "OPT PSEUDOSECTION" mean in dig report?

Tags: dns, dig

Take Facebook as an example, I found `OPT PSEUDOSECTION` doesn't exist in the first query request, but exist in the second try.

What does `OPT PSEUDOSECTION` mean?

Why it doesn't exist in the first try?

[image]

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but you should consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_mechanisms_for_DNS to have a good introduction about this and an answer.

Comment: You might have more luck with this question at unix.stackexhange.com, since `dig` is a Unix command line tool. Definitely ask them, I'm trying to figure out the answer to this as well!

Comment: Been looking into this. Not sure why the section didn't show up on the first try, but here's a post on serverfault with everything I've learned about OPT PSEUDOSECTION: https://serverfault.com/a/1018678/528962